# Not Able to Add New Class To CPT Attachment Image

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development, images

Testing against WordPress 6.0 and using [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_image_tag_class/),  `get_image_tag_class` filter to remove all existing default classes and  add new class `img-fluid` is not working

Here is the code that I am using in `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string' );

function example_add_img_class( $all_the_default_classes ) {
     
    return $all_the_default_classes . ' img-fluid';
}
 
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', 'example_add_img_class' );
```

and I am still getting all default classes? besides the `width="825" height="800"` attributes.
Can you please let me know how I can fix this to remove existing classes and add the new class `img-fluid` and render image without having  `width="825" height="800"` attributes
[image]

Comment: if you rename the `$class` variable to `$all_the_default_classes` the solution should become much clearer

Comment: Well, it looks more clear now but I am not sure if we can call it a solution, since still not doing the job!